# Converting Swift Array to NSArray

Tags: swift

I've just started working with Swift, and I need to convert an Array to an NSArray for the purpose of writing to a plist file. Here's my code:

```
func saveDataToFile() {
        var a:Array = [Any]()
    for thing in self.objects {
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        dictionary["name"] = thing.name
        dictionary["location"] = thing.location
        a.append(dictionary)
    }
    let arr: NSArray = a
    cocoaArray.writeToFile(filePath, atomically:true);
}
```

When I try to convert a into the NSArray arr, I get the error "Cannot convert value of type [Any] to specified type NSArray."

Comment: Can you show the declaration of self.objects. What exactly is it?

Comment: var objects = [AnyObject]()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting `Cannot convert value of type [Any] to specified type NSArray`, because `a` is of type `[Any]` and you cannot bridge that to an `NSArray`. That's because an `NSArray` can only contain instances of Class-types and `Any` can represent an instance of any type.

If you were to declare `a` as `[AnyObject]`, you'll probably be fine. But then you'll also need to change the type of the dictionary to `[String:AnyObject]`.

Or you could use an `NSMutableArray`, and forego the bridging entirely:

```
var a = NSMutableArray()
for thing in objects {
    var dictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
    dictionary["name"] = thing.name
    dictionary["location"] = thing.location
    a.addObject(dictionary)
}
a.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
```

Comment: I think I'll use the NSMutableArray instead, that's much simpler, and eliminates my problem. Thanks!!